How long does it typically take an attorney to draft a software patent?
For each tier of complexity for a software patent, simple, medium, and complex, what is a typical time frame for it to take an attorney to draft the patent. No patent search is involved, just the drafting.

I would say a few weeks. Hard to be more precise. A patent attorney will have many activities going on all times.

Is that assuming that the attorney is working on other client's projects simultaneously?

@BearBileFarmingisTorture You should assume the attorney is working for several clients at any point in time. Not all of those are in the drafting stage. The attorney may suggest a professional prior art search and that might be a good idea.
